# Strange JavaScript behaviour?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a simple function that calls other functions:

```
function update() {
    updateMissiles();
    updatePlayer;
    updateTurbines();

}
```

They are similar to each other in every way except updatePlayer will not run if I put brackets on the end of it. This doesn't break any code but I'm still curious why it does that?

Comment: Without knowing anything about `updatePlayer`, it's impossible to say much. But a function won't run unless it's called, and calling a function means `()`.

Comment: @BogdanProtsenko: What is `updatePlayer`? What do you meand by "_updatePlayer will not run_" and how you check if it has been run?

Comment: What is your specific error message? My guess is that `updatePlayer` is not a function by the time `update` executes. Just before `updatePlayer`, write `console.log(updatePlayer)` to see what the value is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing there's an Exception in the `updatePlayer` method and since you're not calling it in the code you pasted above, you're not getting the Exception.

I would open up the Developer Tools for whatever browser you're using and see if there are any JavaScript Exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused.  `updatePlayer;` doesn't invoke the updatePlayer function.  `updatePlayer();` does.  Something else is going on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more it's impossible to pinpoint exactly, but as a best guess - in the scope of the `update` function, the `updatePlayer` variable is not a function.

Try logging or debugging your javascript to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

A function will run only if you put `()` after it's name.
If you don't put brackets you'll get the function's content.
For example if you have:

```
function updatePlayer(){ alert('This is a player');}
```

And call it without brackets:

```
alert(updatePlayer);
```

the alerted output will be

```
function updatePlayer(){ alert('This is a player');}
```

This is used if you want to use callback functions.